# SQLAlchemy: create dict of foreign key column names to foreign keys

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using the table:

```
class Table3(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'table3'

    pkid = Column('pkid', INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    table1_fkid = Column('table1_fkid', INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey('table1.pkid'), nullable=False)
    table2_fkid = Column('table2_fkid', INTEGER(unsigned=True), ForeignKey('table2.pkid'), nullable=False)
```

I would like to build/obtain the dict:

```
d = {
    'table1_fkid': ForeignKey('table1.pkid'),
    'table2_fkid': ForeignKey('table2.pkid')
}
```

with a method where the object **Table3** is passed as a parameter.  What is the most efficient way to write this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got this, but please post if there is something cleaner:

```
{c.name: c.foreign_keys for c in table.columns if len(c.foreign_keys) > 0}
```